# What's the connection between irreducible polynomials and fixed-frobenius elements in a finite ring?

Tags: permutations, finite-fields, ring-theory

Consider the ring $A_{p,n} = \mathbb{F}_p [x]/ (x^{p^n}-x)$.  It has a basis $\{1, x, x^2, \ldots, x^{p^n - 1}\}$.  The Frobenius endomorphism $x \mapsto x^p$ permutes elements of this basis.  I've made the following observation:

The number of cycles of this permutation is equal to the number of distinct irreducible factors of $x^{p^n} - x$ (which itself is the product of all irreducible polynomials of degree $d$ for all $d|n$).  In other words, the dimension of the fixed frobenius sub-algebra is equal to the number of distinct irreducible factors of $x^{p^n} - x$.

Moreover, the number of cycles of length $d$ is equal to the number of irreducible factors of $x^{p^n} -x$ of degree $d$.

For instance, for $A_{3,2}$ we have the frobenius endomorphism as the permutation $(1)(x \; x^3)(x^2 \; x^6)(x^4)(x^5 \; x^7)(x^8)$, $x^9-x$ factors into $x(x+1)(x+2)(x^2+1)(x^2 +x + 2)(x^2+2x+2)$.

But I only have examples of this happening - how can I prove it or find a counter example?  That is, what is the connection between the cycles of the ``frobenius permutation'' and the factors of $(x^{p^n}-x)$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$ ?

Comment: Looks like a variant of cyclotomic cosets modulo $p^n-1$. Except that $0$ and $p^n-1$ come out different. If you were looking at $\Bbb{F}_p[x]/(x^{p^n-1}-1)$ you would get exactly the cyclotomic cosets.